# iOS - setting the lock screen image

Tags: iphone, ios, lockscreen

I'm planning to use the [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) API to set an image on the lock screen.

Can I do this without actually playing any audio? It's only the lock screen image that I want to change.

If I can do it technically do you think Apple will let it into the app store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Even if you manage to do it, your app will not be accepted by Apple.

Comment: But looks like [this](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fancy-wallpapers-lock-screen/id789446892?mt=8) app has the ability to change background image while still be on App store?

Answer (score 4):

You are not supposed to change the lock screen image programmatically unless you are not planning to release it as an internal app.